# How to clear variable $v$ from logarithmic equation

Tags: logarithms

I have the following:

$6.4 = -\log\dfrac{5-v*0.1}{50+v}$

I would like to know how to solve the equation in order to get $v$'s value. Thank you very much.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: $a=\log b\iff 10^a=b$. (I assume $\log$ is base $10$.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take anti-logarithms of $-6.4 = \log\dfrac{5-v*0.1}{50+v}$ and then it is easy.

For example if your logarithms are base $e$ then $e^{-6.4} = \dfrac{5-v*0.1}{50+v}$